# What is this white box in a battery pack?

Tags: dc-motor, battery-operated

I have an O2 Hurricane canless air system that seems not to charge anymore. I was a bit surprised because it hasn't been through much use or many charging cycles, and customer support was non-responsive, so I decided to take it apart and see if I could at least make it work with direct DC power.

Here's the inside circuit with the battery pack taken out:
[image: canless air motor circuit without battery pack]
The black box is the on switch. Circles 1 and 2 are the metal tabs that were connected to the battery pack, and circle 3 is the white piece I'm wondering about. Because when I plug this circuit straight into the wall (via a 12V DC adaptor), the motor twitches but doesn't spin up.

Here's a close up of the white box:
[image: white box]
I tried for 5 minutes to get a picture where I could make out exactly what the writing above 55*C says, but I couldn't do it, even under a 4x magnifying glass. I'm hoping someone recognizes it just by shape or place in the circuit. The other sides of the box are blank.

Comment: There you have it - 4 answers saying the same thing, two with directions to test...

Comment: It turned out the DC adaptor I was trying to power it with wasn't up to the task. Changing to another adaptor and it works fine. Doh!

Comment: At least that was the good side of wrong... glad it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a thermal fuse or switch.

Without the exact details it would be to limit the temperature of the motor or battery pack.

One way of testing is to see if it works by shorting it but i would not advise using the device without that working properly.

Comment: OK it makes perfect sense that it was tucked into the battery pack then. It was the prevent the batteries from overheating. It's not needed if I'm powering it directly from DC power, right?

Comment: If it was in the battery pack and away from the motor then it should be fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a thermal fuse or circuit breaker.

You could determine if it is a problem by shorting its terminals - if it is open circuit, you should replace it, rather than simply shorting it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is thermal fuse set to trip at 55C

Answer (score 1):

That's a 55 °C thermal fuse for protection.